# How to implement video playback using VideoView inside nested ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-videoview, android-viewpager2

- My intention is to implement nested ViewPager using ViewPager2. Each
  page of the horizontal-scroll ViewPager contains a vertical-scroll
  ViewPager which contains a list of videos by a category. Video
  auto-play when the page visible to the user and stop when the page
  invisible.
- My solution:

`CategoryPagerAdapter` for horizontal-scroll `ViewPager`

```
public class CategoryPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    public CategoryPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new ListVideoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Send category id to ListVideoFragment
        // This fragment contains the vertical-scroll ViewPager
        args.putLong(ListVideopaperFragment.EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID, categories.get(position).getId());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Math.max(categories.size(), 0);
    }

    public void addCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories.addAll(categories);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   }
```

`ListVideoPagerAdapter` for vertical-scroll `ViewPager`

```
    public class ListVideoPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListWallpaperPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;         
        fragment = new VideoPreviewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(EXTRA_VIDEO_URI, videos.get(position).getVideoPath());
        args.putLong(EXTRA_VIDEO_ID, videos.get(position).getId());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Math.max(videos.size(), 0);
    }

    public void addVideos(List<Video> videos) {
        this.videos.addAll(videos);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
   }
```

This is the fragment `VideoPreviewFragment` that contains a `VideoView` as a video player and is contained inside each page of vertical-scroll ViewPager.

```
 private static VideoPreviewFragment fragment = null;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private String videoURI;
    private long videoId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            videoURI = args.getString(EXTRA_VIDEO_URI);
            videoId = args.getLong(EXTRA_VIDEO_ID);          
        }      
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        videoView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        initializePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (videoView != null) {
            videoView.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Playing video:" + videoURI);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (videoView != null && videoView.canPause()) {
            videoView.pause();
            Log.d(TAG, "Pause video: " + videoURI);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
        Log.d(TAG, "releasePlayer:" + videoURI); 
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 
    // When scrolling to another video, the current video will be not visible, stop playback
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(isVisible);
        if (!isVisible) {
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            Log.d(TAG, "releasePlayer:" + videoURI);
        }
    }

    int currentPosition = 0;
    private void initializePlayer() {
        videoView.setVideoURI(getMedia(videoURI));
        videoView.seekTo(1);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared video: " + videoURI);
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion video: " + videoURI);
                videoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        });
     
        videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick VideoView");
                if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                    if (videoView != null && videoView.canPause()) {
                        videoView.pause();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Pause video: " + videoURI);
                    }
                    assert videoView != null;
                    currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                } else {
                    if (currentPosition >= 0){
                        videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
                        if (videoView != null) {
                            videoView.start();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Playing video:" + videoURI + " duration : " + videoView.getDuration());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private Uri getMedia(String videoSource) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(videoSource)) {
            return Uri.parse(videoSource);
        }
        return Uri.parse(videoSource);
    }
  }
```

- My problem is when the app runs, the first video in the list can play
  normally but when I scroll down to the next video, it can't play
  video, just a black screen, although I can see in the debug log
  "Playing video: .....". And it performs strange behavior when
  scrolling up and down, some time video can be played, most of the
  time cannot.

I haven't figured out anything yet, Do you have any ideas? Or can you give me an equivalent solution for this amtter?
Thanks!

Comment: I found this from the debug log when scrolling up to the next video, both two `VideoView`of two `VideoPreviewFragment` which contains the player are detached from the window, that is why video 2nd can't be played and only see a black screen. I check that by adding `videoView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener`. But I don't understand why is that. It should be the 1st `VideoView` detached and 2nd `VideoView` attached to the window. Can you light me up about that.

Comment: And when scrolling back to 1st video both two `VideoView` of two players are attached to the window. So, if I scroll to video 3rd then scroll back to video 2nd, it can be played. What a strange